# Why generic to object type-casting is implicit?

Tags: java, generics

While converting an non-generic class to a generic one, I saw this working :

```
public class TestException<T>
{
    T t;
    Object getObj(){
        return t;   
    }
}
```

When I tried to change the return-type from Object to any other say `String`, I had to type cast it :

```
String getObj(){
    return (String)t;   
}
```

Why generic to object type-casting is implicit ? Couldn't find any implementation on java docs.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be explicit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every class inherits `Object`, so `T` is guaranteed to be implicitly convertible to `Object`.

Answer (score 5):

Since your generic type `T` is unbound, it gets the implicit bound `T extends Object`.  This means that it's fine for it to be returned as an `Object`.

There's no guarantee that `T` is a `String`, so you're forced to cast it (and you run the risk of runtime exceptions if you do and `T` is not a `String`).

Answer (score 1):

even if T wasn't generics type it would have worked. try it yourself!

you can always return something as it super type, same goes for generics

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of every class ISA Object, so you can always cast any reference type value to Object. Only a String object, however,  ISA String.

Comment: I'm not aware of any subtype of `java.lang.String.` Maybe because it's `final.` ;-)